# How do I free the memory while trimming a character array?

Tags: c++

I am coding this in C++. My current issue at hand is that I have to trim the whitespace from the beginning of the character array. I am not allowed to use any string functions. My idea is to count the number of whitespaces at the beginning, allocate memory based on how much less memory I would need in a character array if I didn't have those whitespaces, do so, and then copy over the new string and deallocate the original string.

My issue is that I can't seem to deallocate that string without Visual Studio hitting a break point for me. I can get it working with the code I have below, (not deallocating the roginal strig at all) d=but wouldn't that cause a memory leak?

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class SmartString{  
    private:
        char* str;
    public:
        SmartString ( )
        {
            str = NULL;
        }
        SmartString (char *str){
            int length = 0;
            int copy_index = 0;
            while(str[length] != '\0')
            {
                length++;
            }
            length++;
            char * copy;
            copy = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
            copy = new char[length];
            while(copy_index < length)
            {
                copy[copy_index] = str[copy_index];
                cout << str[copy_index];
                copy_index++;
            }
            this -> str = copy;
        }
        ~ SmartString()
        {
            if(str != NULL)
            {
                delete str;
                free(str);
            }
        }
        void ShowString()
        {
            cout << "[" << str << "]";
        }
        int Size()
        {
            if(str == NULL)
                return 0;
            else
            {
                int i = 0;
                while(str[i] != '\0')
                {
                    i++;
                }
                i++;
                return i;
            }
        }
        **void Trim()
        {
            int counter = 0;
            while (str[counter] == ' ' && counter < Size())
            {
                counter++;
            }       
            int new_length = Size() - (counter + 1);
            char * temp;
            temp = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * new_length);
            temp = new char[new_length];
            int counter_2 = 0;
            while(counter_2 < Size())
            {
                temp[counter_2] = str[counter_2 + counter];
                counter_2++;
            }
            str = temp;
        }** 
};

int main()
{
    char *str;
    str = "   Hello";
    SmartString * s = new SmartString(str);
    str = "Change";
    (*s).Trim();
    (*s).ShowString();

    system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: Don't use `malloc` in C++ (besides the fact that you do *both* and leak memory and **then** double delete). Also, should be `delete [] str;` since you `new[]`.

Comment: Why is there a `new` directly following `malloc`, with the results of both being assigned to `copy`?

Comment: @crashmstr: Yes, but unfortunately, `realloc()` only works with `malloc()`. So `malloc()` seems perfectly reasonable to me, particularly if you need to "trim an array", as the OP says he wants to.

Comment: Also, for using a pointer, it is idiomatic to use `->` instead of `(*).`. Also, absolutely no reason to `new SmartString` (plus you don't `delete` it).

Comment: In addition to the above comments, it looks like you're trying to free a string literal (which leads to UB).

Comment: @crashmstr: That's not a constructive reply.

Comment: @JonathanWood Ok... I don't see them using `realloc` anywhere, plus they are throwing away the `malloc` results by then using `new`, so I don't understand how your comment about using `realloc` with `malloc` makes sense.

Comment: @crashmstr: I'm not sure who "them" and "they" refers to, but  `realloc()` is available in C++. And if you need to resize memory, then `malloc()` and `realloc()` seem valid choices.

Comment: @JonathanWood them/they == user2019645 aka OP aka person asking the question. The code user2019645  has posted shows no `realloc` calls and also shows problems with allocation and de-allocation of memory with double allocations (with C++ and C calls) and double frees (again with both C++ and C calls). *Yes*, `malloc` and `realloc` have very valid uses in C++, but it is not something I would recommend for a beginner learning C++ (oops, why does my class not work with `malloc`).

Comment: You say you can't use string functions, does that mean just std::string? You could simplify this a bit by using the [cstring](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/) header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not used 'delete' in your main function to deallocate your 's' pointer variable, So that the destructor method of your 'SmartString' class never called. In your second constrcutor method, you I've allocated the 'copy' variable twice where it's not need And also you have some mistake in your 'Trim' method.

In your destructor method, You should remove the `free(str);` statement cause the `delete str;` statement will deallocate the 'str'. So there is no need to deallocate twice.

`malloc` - Allocates the requested memory and returns a pointer to it.
`new X;` - Do the same thing but also calls constructor method if X is a class or struct after allocating.
`new X[]` - Allocates dynamic array with the requested memory and returns a pointer to it.

`free` - Deallocates the memory previously allocated.
`delete` - Do the same thing but also calls destructor method if X is a class or struct after deallocating.
`delete[]` - Deallocates the memory previously allocated dynamic array.

`new` and `delete` is the standard memory allocation and deallocation implement of C++ language where `malloc` and `free` is the standard memory allocation and deallocation function of C language.

Here I've rewritten your 'Trim' method:

```
void Trim()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while (str[counter] == ' ' && counter < Size())
        {
            counter++;
        } 
        int new_length = Size() - (counter + 1);
        char * temp;
        // There is no need to allocate twice
        //temp = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * new_length);
        temp = new char[new_length+1];
        int counter_2 = 0;
        while(counter_2 < //Size() ( Here is your big mistake. You should not use 'Size()' here )
                          new_length
                          )
        {
            temp[counter_2] = str[counter_2 + counter];
            counter_2++;
        }
        temp[counter_2] = 0;

        str = temp;
    }
```

And for deallocating, you have to use the 'delete' like this:

```
int main() 
{
    char *str;
    str = "   Hello";
    SmartString * s = new SmartString(str);
    str = "Change";
    (*s).Trim();
    (*s).ShowString();

    // use delete to deallocate a pointer
    delete s;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: My mistake. I was under the impression that free() and delete did different things-- clearly not. I learned java then python in that order, so I'm not used to playing with memory allocation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am getting a HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED when I make the modifications you've suggested. Only if I run both the Trim() function and the deallocation of SmartString s causes this error. I'll be taking another look at my code but I thought I should let you know.

Comment: You need `delete [] x;` if you `x = new char[256];`, in other words, `delete` for `new` (single new object) and `delete []` for `new []` (array).

Comment: Great. So I just found a clause my professor included in our lab that stipulates that we can only use array notation for the purposes of declaring them, haha. So... I have to rewrite everything into pointer notation. Thanks anyways, though. I learned alot.

Answer (score 0):

I see three reasonable approaches to this.

One would be to modify the existing string in-place. Find the position of the first non-space character, then copy from there to the end of the string to positions starting from the first element of the string. This can't be applied to a string literal (or you'll get undefined behavior).

The second would be to allocate a new buffer and copy the data you want to keep into that buffer. In this case, you probably do *not* want to try to modify the original (and, especially, you don't want to try to free its data).

The third would be to (basically) re-implement a class about like `std::string`, that always allocates a buffer in a specific way, so it "knows" how to manipulate that buffer safely. In this case, you could/would have a constructor to create an object from a string literal, so by the time your function was invoked, it would only (even attempt to) manipulate such objects and could never accidentally try to manipulate/modify something like a string literal.